# how can i import react in express . while working on react sever side rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

During import react js in my project, I am getting an error as below :

```
error : /Users/shivakrishna/reactRender/server.js:1
            (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
                at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
                at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
                at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
                at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:694:28)
                at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
                at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
                at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
                at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
                at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:12)
                at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:526:15)
```

Code is as below:

server.js :

```
        import React from 'react';
        const express = require('express')
        const ReactDomServer = require('react-dom/server');
        const app = express();
        app.use(express.static('build'))
        app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
        })

        app.listen(3000,()=>{ })
        webpack.sever.js : 
        const path = require('path');
        const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
        module.exports = {
            target : "node" ,
            entry : './server.js',
            output :{
                filename : 'bundle.js',
                path : path.resolve(__dirname,'build'),
                publicPath :'/build'
            },
            module:{
                rules:[{
                    test :/\.jsx$/ ,
                    loader :'babel-loader',
                    exclude:'/node_modules/',
                    presets :[
                            'react',
                            'stage-0',
                            ['env',{
                                target : {browser : ['last 2 versions']}
                            }]
                        ]

                }],

            },
            externals :[webpackNodeExternals()]
        }
```

package.json :

```
            {
              "name": "reactrender",
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "description": "",
              "main": "index.js",
              "scripts": {
                "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch",
                "webpack:start": "nodeman --watch build --exec node build/bundle.js",
                "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel webpack:*"
              },
              "author": "",
              "license": "ISC",
              "dependencies": {
                "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
                "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
                "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
                "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
                "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
                "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
                "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
                "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
                "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
                "express": "^4.17.1",
                "nodeman": "^1.1.2",
                "react": "^16.8.6",
                "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
                "react-router": "^5.0.1",
                "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
                "webpack": "^4.35.2",
                "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
                "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
              },
              "devDependencies": {
                "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
                "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.0",
                "@babel/register": "^7.4.4",
                "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.0",
                "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0"
              }
            }
```

Comment: Don't mix `import` and `require`.

Comment: You can not mix the client side and server side code together. You can use Node JS API in your client-side code of react js